# How I can clear textbox text before ajax form submit event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I want to clear textbox after ajax posting.

```
<div style="padding: 5px; background-color: Silver;">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.room_id.ToString() }))
  {
    <div style="padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;">
        @Html.TextBox("textbox_message", null, new { @class = "text_yorum", id = "text_box_chat" })
        @Html.Hidden("oda_id", Model.room_id)
    </div>
  }
</div>

<div id="@Model.room_id" style="height:400px;overflow-y:scroll;position: relative;">
    @Html.Action("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new { room_id = Model.room_id })
</div>
```

there are a lot of example, but they do not work. I m already using this code, but it is too slow.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
   $.get('@Url.Action("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new { room_id = Model.room_id }) ', {}, function (view) {
       $("#@Model.room_id").html(view);
       $("#text_box_chat").val("");
   });
});
```

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the Ajax function. But anyways I believe the key to your problem is that you have no success function. Try something like this.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'yourfile.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {

          $('#myform input').val("");

        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending 2 AJAX requests. One sent by the Ajax.BeginForm helper and one inside your custom .submit handler. You could specify a callback which will be executed after the AJAX request completes in the AjaxOptions:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.room_id.ToString(), OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
{
    ...
}
```

and clear the input inside this callback:

```
function onSuccess() {
    $("#text_box_chat").val("");    
}
```

You don't need to subscribe to the .submit event of the form as you did and send an AJAX request. That's what the Ajax.BeginForm helper already does.

Comment: Glad I could help. You may consider [marking this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it if it helped you solve the problem.